# Can I specify webdriver.gecko.driver in node.json using selenium grid?

Tags: java, json, windows, selenium, selenium-grid

I have a selenium v3.4.0 script in Eclipse with these commands in -

```
beforeClass() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("geckodriver: "+geckoPath);    // set to  "C:\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\geckodriver.exe"
        //    FOR FF 53.0.2
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoPath);
        baseUrl = "http://www.expedia.co.uk";
        nodeURL = "http://192.168.124.128:5555/wd/hub";    //    WindowsVM
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), caps);

        searchPage = new SearchPageFactory(driver);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
```

This script runs perfectly well on my Windows 10 VM when I start the node with the DOS command -

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\geckodriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://ASUSLaptop:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=firefox,version=53.0.2,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS
```

If I start the node with -

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -nodeConfig GridNode.json
```

where the Gridnode.json is -

```
{
"capabilities":
[
    {
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "maxInstances": 1,
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
    "webdriver.gecko.driver": "C:\\Selenium\\selenium-java-3.4.0\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe"
    },
    {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "maxInstances": 1,
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
    "webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:\\Selenium\\selenium-java-3.4.0\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"
    },
    {
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "maxInstances": 1,
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
],
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"maxSession": 2,
"port": 5555,
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hub": "http://ASUSLaptop:4444",
"nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
"nodePolling": 5000,
"role": "node",
"unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
"downPollingLimit": 2,
"debug": false,
"servlets" : [],
"withoutServlets": [],
"custom": {}
}
```

..then the same script fails, with the error -

```
geckodriver: C:\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\geckodriver.exe
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass beforeClass
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Command duration or timeout: 272 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ASUSLAPTOP', ip: '192.168.124.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at SeleniumGrid.L168SeleniumGrid_Win_Firefox.beforeClass(L168SeleniumGrid_Win_Firefox.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass afterClass
SKIPPED: test
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Command duration or timeout: 272 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ASUSLAPTOP', ip: '192.168.124.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at SeleniumGrid.L168SeleniumGrid_Win_Firefox.beforeClass(L168SeleniumGrid_Win_Firefox.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

My Grid Console shows the configuration as -

```
browserTimeout: 0
debug: false
help: false
port: 5555
role: node
timeout: 1800
cleanUpCycle: 5000
host: 192.168.124.128
maxSession: 2
capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, webdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\geckodriver.exe, maxInstances=1, platform=WIN10}]
capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, webdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, platform=WIN10}]
capabilities: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=internet explorer, maxInstances=1, platform=WIN10}]
downPollingLimit: 2
hub: http://ASUSLaptop:4444
id: http://192.168.124.128:5555
hubHost: ASUSLaptop
hubPort: 4444
nodePolling: 5000
nodeStatusCheckTimeout: 5000
proxy: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
register: true
registerCycle: 5000
remoteHost: http://192.168.124.128:5555
unregisterIfStillDownAfter: 60000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to pass the geckodriver path in the command line itself. I tried passing the path in both capability and configuration json but in vain. You can read about the issue here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3051

Answer (score 0):

You can code e.g like this on having browser as

```
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase(Consts.FIREFOX)) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", getRootDir() + "/src/main/java/configuration/geckodriver");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was asking how to specify webdriver.gecko.driver using a node.json configuration file?

Comment: if you are using grid then you can specify in .json file this{
"capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "browser-version": "38.8.0",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      **"webdriver.gecko.driver" : "path to gecko driver"** -----> add path to gecko driver
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],

Comment: As in my original post, the json already has this in it. Also get the same problem with chromedriver. This works from the command prompt  -

    java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=.\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://ASUSLaptop:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=chrome,version=58.0.3029.110,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS
..this json doesn't..

    {"capabilities":[{"browserName": "chrome","maxInstances": 1,"seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver","webdriver.chrome.driver": ".\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"} ] }

Comment: This is related to stackoverflow.com/questions/42117425/…. Is it possible to specify **any** webdriver.<browser>.driver in the node's json? The responses to 42117425 suggest not